# MongoDB. Hay manera de relacionar colecciones?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Estoy trabajando con una app CRUD con el MEAN stack para llevar un control de pacientes, tengo un requerimiento de agregar una historia médica al paciente con la particularidad de que cuando elimine un paciente, se borre solo el paciente, y su historial médico permanezca en la BD.
Lo único que se me ha ocurrido es crear otro schema de `historia.js` y hacer la referencia en el schema `pacientes.js`

Anexo parte del código de ambos

**historia.js**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Paciente = mongoose.model("Paciente");

var historia_schema = new Schema({

    descripcion: {type: String, required: true},
    paciente: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Paciente", required: true}

});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Historia", historia_schema);
```

**Paciente.js**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var dateTime = require("node-datetime");


//Modelo del paciente
var paciente_schema = new Schema({

    nombre: {type: String, required: true},
    estado: {type: String, required: true, default: "En espera"},
    fecha: {type: String, required: true},
    edad: {type: String, required: true},
    sexo: {type: String, required: true},
    direccion: {type: String, required: true},
    contacto: {type: String, required: true}

});


//exportando modelo del paciente
module.exports = mongoose.model("Paciente", paciente_schema);

//var dt = dateTime.create();
//var fechapc = dt.format('Y-m-d H:M');
//console.log(fechapc);
//if(req.body.fecha === fechapc){
//  Paciente.estado = "Atendido";
//}
```

app.js

```
//importando paquetes y módulos necesarios
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Paciente = require("./models/pacientes");
var dateTime = require("node-datetime");
var Historia = require("./models/historia");





//asignando express a app para inicializarlo
var app = express();

//conexión a mongoDB, pasamos el servidor(localhost), y el nombre de la BDD(pacientes)
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var mongoDB = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/pacientes', {
    useMongoClient: true
});


app.use(bodyParser.json()); //leyendo parámetros de una petición JSON
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); //facilita la lectura de los parámetros de una petición
app.use(express.static("client")); //servido de archivos estáticos


//obteniendo los pacientes
app.get("/app/pacientes", function(req, res){
//find busca todos los datos de la DB
    Paciente.find(function(err, pacientes){
        if(err){
            res.send("Ocurrió error obteniendo los pacientes");
        }else{
            res.send(pacientes);
        }
//Paciente.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id, fecha: {$lt: Date()}}, {$set: {estado: 'Atendido'}});
    });

});


//obteniendo UN paciente
app.get("/app/pacientes/:id", function(req, res){
//método findOne el cual recibe el id del paciente a buscar en la DB
    Paciente.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id, fecha: {$lt: Date()}}, {$set: {estado: 'Atendido'}}, function(err, paciente){
        if(err){
            res.send("Ocurrió error obteniendo el paciente deseado");
        }else{
            res.json(paciente);
        }

    });
});


//agregando pacientes
app.post("/app/pacientes", function(req, res){
//creando paciente con los datos enviados por el user en el cuerpo de la petición
    Paciente.create(req.body, function(err, pacientes){
        if(err){
            res.send("Error al agregar paciente");
        }else{
            res.json(pacientes);
        }

    });
});



//actualizando paciente
app.put("/app/pacientes/:id", function(req, res){
//creamos una variable(actualiza) la cual tomará los atributos a actualizar y se enviará como un query en el método update
    var actualiza = {

        nombre: req.body.nombre,
        estado: req.body.estado,
        fecha: req.body.fecha,
        edad: req.body.edad,
        sexo: req.body.sexo,
        contacto: req.body.contacto

    };
//encontramos un paciente y lo actualizamos, pasamos el query con los atributos actualizados
    Paciente.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, actualiza, function(err, paciente){     
        if(err){
            res.send("Ocurrió error actualizando" + err);
        }else{
            res.json(paciente);
        }

    });

/* === SOL === */
//  req.body.fecha = new Date(req.body.fecha);
//  console.log("=== "+req.body.fecha);
//  Paciente.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id, fecha: {$lt: Date()}}, {$set: {estado: 'Atendido'}});

});


//borrar paciente
app.delete("/app/pacientes/:id", function(req, res){
//método para encontrar y eliminar un dato en la DB, el _id es el identificador en la DB
    Paciente.findOneAndRemove({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, pacientes){
        if(err){
            res.send("Error al eliminar el paciente");
        }else{
            res.json(pacientes);
        }

    });
});

//agregando historia
app.post("/app/pacientes/:id/addhistoria", function(req, res){
    Historia.create(req.body, function(err, historias){
        if(err){
            res.send("Error al agregar paciente");
        }else{
            res.json(historias);
        }
    });
});


//app corriendo en puerto 8888
app.listen(8888, function() {
    console.log("App corriendo en 8888");
});
```

Las historias me las guarda en otra colección pero cuando hago la `ref: "Paciente` en historia.js, no me guarda nada. Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: en realidad la relacion no existe, lo idea es que una coleccion sea un conjunto de datos que tu necesitas, lo ideal es que tengas dos colecciones y que estas cuando las recorras tengas los valores necesarios para iterar

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrias hacer es poner un campo extra para saber si se tiene que mostrar en tu sistema que estás realizando, esto si no mal recuerdo se llama borrado lógico.

Un ejemplo seria agregar el un campo llamado fecha_borrado, cuando borres un paciente pon una fecha para saber que dia lo "sacaste" del sistema y filtra en base a ese campo.

Answer (score 0):

Para relacionar tus colecciones deberías tener el historial como atributo de la colección paciente:

```
//Modelo del paciente
var paciente_schema = new Schema({
    nombre: {type: String, required: true},
    estado: {type: String, required: true, default: "En espera"},
    fecha: {type: String, required: true},
    edad: {type: String, required: true},
    sexo: {type: String, required: true},
    direccion: {type: String, required: true},
    contacto: {type: String, required: true}
    historial: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "historiales", required: true}
});

var historia_schema = new Schema({
    descripcion: {type: String, required: true}
    fecha_registro: {type: Date, default: Date.now() } // quizá quieras esto y otros datos importantes ...    
});
```

Observa que puse los nombres de las colecciones en plural, según recuerdo, mongoose te crea las colecciones de ese modo aunque las coloques en singular, a mí me ha pasado solamente que agregue una "s" al final. Para que lo tengas en cuenta.

Si lo defines de este modo, tus consultas podrían ser algo como:

```
Paciente.
  find().
  populate('historiales').
  exec(function (err, pacientes) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log(pacientes);
    // imprime un array de pacientes con sus historiales
  });
```

Por otro lado, quizá sea buena que al eliminar un paciente lo hagas con borrado lógico tal como comentan en la otra respuesta ya que si el paciente se da de alta de nuevo, tengas sus registros. Eso se hace colocando un atributo nuevo al modelo de paciente donde indicas si está activo o no. Esto a menos que los requerimientos así lo digan porque los pacientes fallezcan y no sea necesario darlos de alta de nuevo ...

Answer (score 0):

Aunque en MongoDB también se pueden plantear relaciones sí se piensa a las colecciones como tablas, la realidad es que para plantear relaciones mejor mantenerse en bases relacionales.
Sí vas a plantear un esquema de 1 a N, es decir un paciente tiene muchas historias, es decir la historia se compone por otros elementos menores, la mejor idea es plantear un documento embebido, como este JSON de ejemplo:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(""),
    "nombre" : "Nombre del Paciente",
    "estado" : "Tipo de Estado",
    "fechaAlta" : ISODate("1995-01-22T00:27:00.057Z"),
    "fechaNacimiento" : ISODate("2018-08-07T00:27:00.057Z"),
    "direccion" : "Direccion",
    "contacto" : "Contacto",
    "eliminado" : parseInt(0),
    "historia" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId(),
            "descripcion" : "Descripcion de la historia",
            "fechaConsulta" : ISODate("2018-08-07T00:31:29.648Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId(),
            "descripcion" : "Descripcion de la historia",
            "fechaConsulta" : ISODate("2018-08-07T00:31:29.648Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Y controlar una variable eliminado, que al realizar una búsqueda de pacientes solo devuelva los que tienen el estado en 1, es decir aplicar una regla de negocio.